# Jquery validation of input array elements manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" name="member_name[]" size="13" value="">  
<input type="text" name="member_name[]" size="13" value="">
<input type="text" name="member_name[]" size="13" value="">
<input type="text" name="member_name[]" size="13" value="">
```

How do i validate these 4 fields so that they are not blank.. without using jquery validate plugin.?

Comment: Validate *what*? Are those required fields? E-mail addresses? Please clarify your question.

Comment: updated question.. please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input:submit').click(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        $("input:text[name^='member_name']").each(function() {
            if (!$.trim($(this).val()).length) {
                alert('Name Field should not leave empty');
                return false; // or e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cancel the form submission by registering a [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event handler and [prevent the default behavior](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) if one of your fields is empty:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    if ($("input:text[name='member_name\\[\\]'][value='']", this).length) {
        window.alert("No member name should be empty.");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** As naveen correctly points out, the code above would still submit the form if the fields only contain whitespace. You can use [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) with [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to fix the problem:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    if ($("input:text[name='member_name\\[\\]']", this).filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) == "";
        }).length) {
        window.alert("No member name should be empty.");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var valid = true;
$('input').each(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "") {
     valid = false;
  }
});

// use valid here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var invalidInputs = $('input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == "";
});

var valid = invalidInputs.length == 0
```

Comment: @naveen: You're not really supposed to change someone's answer like that! Not that I mind, but it's not the done thing!

Comment: i am sorry if i have offended you.

Answer (score 0):

Not most advance, but simple & clear method.

```
 $("form").submit(function(event) {

    var inputLength = $('input[type="text"]').val().length;  // check for value length

    if ($('input').val().length > 0) {
        // submit if input value is length > 0 
        alert('Form submitted.');
    }
    else {
        // error if input value is NOT length > 0 
        alert('Fill the form.');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```